# Why didn't my edit go in the Review Queue? And if it did why didn't I get +2 rep?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

I edited [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/906208) to show the current terminology, and was expecting the canned response saying it was waiting for peer review - however the question updated immediately.

My rep at the time was 1760, but according to the [Privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) page in the Help Centre one needs 2000 rep so that:

> Edits to any question or answer are applied immediately

It could be that someone was in the Suggested Edits review queue and accepted it near enough simultaneously to my posting, but then I would've expected a [Reputation change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) as:

> suggested edit is accepted: +2

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: From the faq: *A much lower reputation (100 instead of 2000) is needed to freely edit a community wiki post originally made by someone else*

Comment: @Rick In particular, this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/562482) states what Shadow wrote, plus it also states "Edits suggested by users with less than 100 reputation will still provide +2 reputation to the editor when approved". This suggests that those members with 100 or more reputation, such as yourself, don't get a +2 reputation change.

Comment: Well it's normal to not know about CW, that's what we have meta sites for, so we can ask and learn. :)